# Eventhough the values are same, the flow of control jumps to the else condition! Why does this happen?Is there any solution to this?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am comparing a value saved using shared preference with a value read from the user.Eventhough both the values are same(when checked in the logcat itself), the correct if condition is not getting triggered.Attaching the code snippet below :

```
     val inp_mail_str=inp_mail.text.trim()
        val inp_pswd_str=inp_pswd.text.trim()
        sp = context?.let {it.getSharedPreferences("Registration Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}
        val db_mail=sp?.getString("Email","")?.trim()
        val db_pswd=sp?.getString("Password","")?.trim()
        if (inp_mail_str == db_mail && inp_pswd_str == db_pswd)
            Toast.makeText(context ,"Login Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else if(inp_mail_str == " ")
            Toast.makeText(context,"Please enter a username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        else
            Toast.makeText(context,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Can you tell which line do you expect to be executed vs which line is actually being executed?

Comment: I expect this line to be executed =>    Toast.makeText(context ,"Login Succesfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()     , but the else if condition gets executed